# I have line counts in batch script from 3 different files and want to add the numbers and print it to an output file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using the following batch script to generate a text file that shows the number of lines in three different .bch files.  (This gives me a count of how many records were processed in each .bch process)

It's working but I would like to add a line to the output file that adds the three values together so that I have one cumulative count for all three files.

```
@ECHO OFF

type NUL > output_%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.txt

cd c:\batch

for %%G in (C:\batch\*.bch) do find /c /v "_+_" %%G >>ipconfig >> c:\batch\output_%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.txt 


EXIT
```

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the count in a variable per iteration and add them all together as you go:

```
set Count=0
for %%G in (C:\batch\*.bch) do (
  for %%C in ('find /c /v "" "%%G"') do (
    set /a Count+=%%C
    >> output.txt echo %%C
  )
)
>> output.txt echo %Count%
```

A few side notes:

1. Don't use `exit` in a batch file unless your goal is to actually exit the command interpreter (which is very rarely the case). Usually you want to exit the *batch file*, which can be done with either `exit /b` or `goto :eof`.
2. Use an invariant date format for time stamps, instead of slicing the `%Date%` pseudo-variable. This can be done with

   ```
   for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_utctime get /format:list') do 2>nul set /a "%%a"
   rem Leading zeroes
   if %Month% LSS 10 set Month=0%Month%
   if %Day% LSS 10 set Day=0%Day%
   if %Hour% LSS 10 set Hour=0%Hour%
   if %Minute% LSS 10 set Minute=0%Minute%
   if %Second% LSS 10 set Second=0%Second%
   echo C:\batch\output_%Year%-%Day%-%Month%.txt
   ```
3. Use `pushd` and `popd` for changind directories because that's easier to undo. In any case, your `cd C:\batch` will fail if the current directory is not on `C:`; it would need the `/D` switch for that to work properly.

Comment: `set Count+=%%C` --> I might be wrong, but this won't work, as you are not using the `/A` switch when calling `SET`, and you are using the non-expanded value of `Count`, where you should enable delayed expansion and use `!Count!` instead, no? I haven't tried your code though, I might be wrong here.

Comment: You're right. The `/a` was missing. Without it `+=` doesn't make any sense, anyway because it would try setting the value for a variable `Count+`. And `set /a` is impervious to non-delayed variable expansion because it doesn't have to use `%Variables%`. So no need to use delayed expansion here (which is just another concept I would have to explain – again).